# How to set langage for translator in controller

Tags: web-services, symfony

I am trying to make a web service that allows for a system of translation 
So I recovered in json 
the term to be translated and the language that which I have to translate 
My problem is I can not change the defaultLocal in the controller

```
class TranslateController extends RestController
```

{

```
/**
 * @param ARDParamFetcher $paramFetcher
 * @RequestParam(name="lang", requirements="[a-zA-Z0-9_]+", description="language.") 
 * @RequestParam(name="msg", requirements="[a-zA-Z0-9_]+", description="message.")             
 */
public function translateAction(ARDParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
{       
    $lang = $paramFetcher->get('lang');
    $msg = $paramFetcher->get('msg');
    $b = $this->get('translator')->setLocale($lang)->trans($msg);
    print_r($b);
    exit();
    return $this->view(array());
}
```

}

and here is the content of my file messages.fr.yml

```
# messages.fr.yml
TXT_1 : il y a %count% objet
```

Any help please

Comment: did you check your `$msg` and `$lang` var? Also you'll probably need to pass `count` to this translation: `->trans($msg, ['%count%' => $someVar], 'messages');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here is what to write :

```
$lang = $paramFetcher->get('lang');
$msg = $paramFetcher->get('msg');
$request = $this->getRequest();
$request->setLocale($lang);
$t = $this->get('translator')->trans($msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled the translator in config file:

```
framework:
    translator: { fallback: %locale% }
```

For syntax, see @Roma comment.

Comment: yes I test the content of my variables 
but what I want is just that it appears to me il y a %count% objet
and that I can assign the controller language I don't know if my syntax is good or not to set local